# ionic 3 - How can I determine the direction of the title to right to left or even center it?

Tags: ionic3

I'm using ionic 3. The default title direction if left to right.

How can I make the direction of the title to right to left or even center the title?

Answer (score 0):

**Right**

The best way I found is by adding the following to app.scss:

```
ion-title {
   text-align: right;
}
```

**Left**

If there are some titles that you want to stay with left to right direction, just add an id to this titles, as following:

`<ion-title id="main_title">`

and add in your app.scss:

`#main_title {
    text-align: left;
}`

**Center**

In addition, using this way you can also center the titles by following:

`#main_title {
    text-align: center;
}`